# How to respond via an JsonResult from Asp.Net Core middleware?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, middleware

I would like to respond via a `JsonResult` from a piece of Asp.Net Core middleware but it's not obvious how to accomplish that.  I have googled around alot but with little success.  I can respond via a `JsonResult` from a global `IActionFilter` by setting the `ActionExecutedContext.Result` to the `JsonResult` and that's cool.  But in this case I want to effectively return a `JsonResult` from my middleware.  How can that be accomplished?

I framed the question with regard to the `JsonResult` `IActionResult` but ideally the solution would work for using any `IActionResult` to write the response from the middleware.

Answer (score 22):

Middleware is a really low-level component of ASP.NET Core. Writing out JSON (efficiently) is implemented in the MVC repository. Specifically, in the [JSON formatters](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/5fca8da66576608473adc70f6be0e3bab9102f12/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json) component.

It basically boils down to writing JSON on the response stream. In its simplest form, it can be implemented in middleware like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// ...

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var result = new SomeResultObject();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
}
```

Comment: @Hank, thanks for your response.  I'm aware I could use Response.WriteAsync to send the raw json but such an approach is prone to overlooking things like forgetting to set the `content-type` repsonse header to "application/json; charset=utf-8".  :-)  That's why I specifically asked how to respond via a JsonResult rather than simply how to send a json response.  Also, I framed the question with regard to the `JsonResult` `IActionResult` but ideally the solution would work for using any `IActionResult` to write the response from the middleware.  I'll update my question to indicate this.

Comment: @RonC `IActionResult` and `JsonResult` are MVC primitives. Middleware is far lower in the layering of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Hank, I know.  So the question kinda boils down to how to we reach higher up into the stack to leverage a feature of MVC and do it from a place _much_ lower in the stack, ie. the middleware.

Comment: It doesn't work that way, unfortunately. Getting something to work will be extremely hacky I think. Maybe wrap a TestServer inside your middleware and return what it gives you (via MVC inside the TestServer - like I said, hacky.)

Answer (score 18):

For others that may be interested in how to return the output of a `JsonResult` from middleware, this is what I came up with:

```
  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult(new { msg = "Some example message." });
        RouteData routeData = context.GetRouteData();
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
        ActionContext actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, actionDescriptor);
        await result.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
    }
```

This approach allows a piece of middleware to return output from a `JsonResult` and the approach is close to being able to enable middleware to return the output from any `IActionResult.` To handle that more generic case the code for creating the `ActionDescriptor` would need improved.  But taking it to this point was sufficient for my needs of returning the output of a `JsonResult`.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and worked for me. The voodoo here is the ExecuteResultAsync is writing to the response stream for you.

Comment: @BinaryPatrick It's software development not something yucky. It turns out that even in a typically controller, when `return View(this);` is executed it returns a `ViewResult` that does not output anything immediately.  Then later in the pipeline, the .NET framework calls `ExecuteResultAsync` to render that `Result` to the response stream. So the approach of this answer simply uses what I found from digging into the .NET Core source code. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 8):

As explained by @Henk Mollema, I have also made use of Newtonsoft.Json JsonConvert class to serialize the object into JSON through SerializeObject method. For ASP.NET Core 3.1 I have used JsonConvert inside the Run method. Following solution worked for me:

Startup.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// ...

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
    {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                message = "Yay! I am a middleware"
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of ASP.NET Core 5.0, you can use `WriteAsJsonAsync` to write JSON to the response stream. This method handles serialization and setting the content type header appropriately.

For example

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

// ..

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var result = new SomeResultObject();
    await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow.  This is a nice additional answer.